# Best way for for loop checking JS

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use a for loop to check if all values are true.

JS:

```
class Obj {
  constructor(a) {
    this.a = a;
  }
  check(x) {
//some code
  return correct; //true or false
  }  
}
myList = [
  new Obj(1),
  new Obj(5),
  new Obj(3)
]
var count = 0;
for (let x in myList) {
  if (myList[x].check(0)) {
  count++;
  }
}
if (count == myList.length) {
  console.log("pass");
} else {
  console.log("fail");
}
```

Is there a more direct way to do this using plain JS?

Comment: Better how?  Can you rephrase your question so it is less subjective?

Comment: [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every), e.g. `const allPassed = myList.every(x => x.check(0))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Array.prototype.every()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every).

```js
class Obj {
  constructor(a) {
    this.a = a;
  }
  check(x) {
  //some code
  return true; //true or false
  }  
}
myList = [
  new Obj(1),
  new Obj(5),
  new Obj(3)
]

if (myList.every(x => x.check(0))) {
  console.log("pass");
} else {
  console.log("fail");
}
```